# Python Homework - creating a pattern that also has spaces

Tags: python

Problem: Write a program that creates a pattern like the one below. Let the user input a non-negative integer to determine the number of lines of the pattern.
The sample output would take input, then have one blank line, then each next line would have a # (space) #, with increasing amount of spaces as count continues.
Example, entering the number 4 would produce one empty line; two pounds on the second line; one pound, one space, one pound on the third line; one pound, two spaces, one pound on the last line.

```
lines = int(input("Enter number of lines for pattern: "))
for a in range(lines):
for b in range(a + 1):
print('#', end='')
print()
```

Above code gives me close to what I want, but it is pounds all across instead of spaces between the two pound signs. I have no idea how to put the spaces there, any help would be awesome.

Comment: To simply print a space you would use print(" "). A space despite the fact it's empty is still considered a character. Which is why the quotations are needed.

Comment: What's desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You can format the output with a variable width:

```
lines = int(input("Enter number of lines for pattern: "))
for a in range(lines):
    print('#%*s' % (a, '#') if a else '')
```

This outputs:

```
(blank line)
##
# #
#  #
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try:

```
for a in range(lines):
    print('#%s#' % ((a-1)*' ') if a else '')
```

Example output:

```
Enter number of lines for pattern: 4

##
# #
#  #
```